# Colocar diferentes TextView encima de ImageView siempre en el mismo lugar

Tags: android, android-layout

¡Hola! Lo que necesito es que los `textview` siempre estén en el mismo lugar del `imageview` usando `match_parent` para `layout_width` y `layout_height` en el.

Así es como quiero que quede en cualquier pantalla (La prueba sería en una pantalla 5'5):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si pongo por ejemplo en 4'7, pasa esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado `RelativeLayout`, `ConstraintLayout`, `FrameLayout` y sigo sin conseguir lo que digo.

`layout`:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.github.siyamed.shapeimageview.StarImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_carta"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        app:siStrokeCap="round"
        app:siStrokeJoin="round"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/carta"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/cartabase" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginStart="76dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:text="NIVEL 1"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginStart="76dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="182dp"
        android:text="NIVEL 2"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginStart="76dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="217dp"
        android:text="NIVEL 3"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginStart="76dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
        android:text="NIVEL 4"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginStart="76dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="287dp"
        android:text="NIVEL 5"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginStart="76dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="320dp"
        android:text="NIVEL 6"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

¿Cuál sería la manera correcta? ¡Gracias!

Comment: Hola amig@, lo que no entiendo es como se podrían mover los textos fuera de los cuadros blancos! :| Son textviews o es otro tipo de contenedor?

Comment: son textview, pero al cambiar de pantalla se muevan @Jorgesys

Comment: Entonces la imagen es de color negro y contiene esos cuadros blancos , es así ? @UserNameYo

Comment: si, todo eso es el .png, menos las letras, eso son textview @Jorgesys

Comment: podrías usar percentlayout si no quieres escribir mucho código, sino tendrías que crear tu propio viewgroup.

Comment: percentlayout ya es obsoleto (deprecated), en su lugar estan los ConstraintLayout. En este caso se debe crear layouts para diferentes tamaños así como los dimens

Comment: Una posible solución sería adaptar la imagen a cada una de las resoluciones y hacerla coincidir con los TextView.
Otra solución sería desde código llevarte los diferentes TextView a una localización en concreto según la resolución.